# MySQL: optimization of table (indexing, foreign key) with no primary keys

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, indexing, primary-key

Each member has 0 or more orders. Each order contains at least 1 item.
memberid - varchar, not integer - that's OK (please do not mention that's not very good, I can't change it).
So, thera 3 tables: members, orders and order_items. Orders and order_items are below:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`orderid` INT(11)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`memberid` VARCHAR( 20 ),
`Time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`info` VARCHAR( 3200 ) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid) ,
FOREIGN KEY (memberid) REFERENCES members(memberid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
`orderid` INT(11)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`item_number_in_cart` tinyint(1) NOT NULL , --- 5 items in cart= 5 rows
`price` DECIMAL (6,2) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES orders(orderid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

So, order_items table looks like:

**orderid - item_number_in_cart - price:**

...

1000456 - 1  - 24.99

1000456 - 2  - 39.99

1000456 - 3  - 4.99

1000456 - 4  - 17.97

1000457 - 1  - 20.00

1000458 - 1  - 99.99

1000459 - 1  - 2.99

1000459 - 2  - 69.99

1000460 - 1  - 4.99

...

As you see, **order_items** table has no primary keys (and I think there is no sense to create an auto_increment id for this table, because once we want to extract data, we always extract it as `WHERE orderid='1000456' order by item_number_in_card asc` - the whole block, id woudn't be helpful in queries).
Once data is inserted into order_items, it's not UPDATEd, just SELECTed.

The questions are:

- I think it's a good idea to put index on item_number_in_cart. Could anybody please confirm that?
- Is there anything else I have to do with order_items to increase the performance, or that looks pretty good? I could miss something because I'm a newbie.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there no quantity field for `order_items`, or did you elide columns  to simplify the example?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Yes, I removed several rows. They are selected and inserted then and only then, when price is selected or inserted.

Comment: Do you mean you removed several columns?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. Yes, I mean columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary keys can span multiple columns. You can't use the `PRIMARY` attribute of columns to do this, but you can define a separate primary key with multiple columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
    `orderid` INT(11)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `item_number_in_cart` tinyint(1) NOT NULL , --- 5 items in cart= 5 rows
    `price` DECIMAL (6,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (orderid, item_number_in_cart),
    FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES orders(orderid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Moreover, a primary key is simply a unique key where every column is not null with a certain name; you can create your own unique keys on non-nullable columns to get the same effects.

You'll not likely get much of a performance improvement by indexing `item_number_in_cart`; as the number of line items for a given order will tend to be small, sorting by `item_number_in_cart` won't take much time or memory. However, including the column in a primary key will help with data consistency.

Comment: I'm not sure I can ask a question after I checked my question as resolved, but... After I declared (orderid, item_number_in_cart) as a primary key, it will be indexed as well. Can't it reduce, but not to increase the performance? MySQL will index this primary key automatically, but I will never SELECT any query by "WHERE orderid='1234567' and item_number_in_cart='3'", only by  "WHERE orderid='1234567' order by item_number_in_cart asc". So, can't it be useless or even worse - to declare PRIMARY KEY (orderid, item_number_in_cart)?

Comment: @Haradzieniec: if you have more questions that stand on their own merits, you can post them as new questions. "When can indices reduce MySQL performance?" is a fair question, though it may have been asked before. If the questions are extensions of what you've already asked, you can edit your question ("When (if ever) will indexing `item_number_in_cart` degrade performance?" could be an extension of your first question). When editing be careful about invalidating existing answers, which is perfectly permissible if your original statement of the question turns out to be inaccurate or imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

Index on `item_number_in_cart` won't be used. It's tiny int, not selective enough, and won't even considered by the engine once you have 2 records. You can add it as a second column to the existing index on `orderid` (since you created FK constraint on `orderid`, mysql automatically adds an index on this field).
You say that data in `order_items` never updated, but I think it can be deleted; doing so without primary key will be problematic.

Comment: "You can add it as a second column to the existing index on orderid" - whad does it mean - "to add it as a second column to the existing index"?

Comment: As Outis did in his answer to you, (PRIMARY KEY (orderid, item_number_in_cart),)
which prompted your extra question about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd be having an autoinc anyway, as I'm a big believer in surrogate keys, but as suggested by alex07 an index, or even primary key of orderid,item_number_in_cart should sort things out. Note the order by item_number will be using a two pass sort, (get the data and then sort it in the number order) so an index / key will chop that out straight off so you'd want that index even with a surrogate key.